# How does a mail user agent know the name of the sender, if the email address does not contain the user's name

Tags: email, email-client, mail-server

I received an email, and the sender's name is User X, but the email address is noreply@example.com.

How is this possible? Are there any extra information that is sent in an email?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the header of the email is written as follows: `Title <email@address.ext>`

If the email address is written using that format, a client will understand that the Title is the name, and only displays that, but uses the email address as actual method of knowing where to send the email to.

The headers of an email will show something like this:

```
TO: You <you@example.com>
FROM: Me <me@example.com>
Date: 1-1-1970, 0:00
Title: Hello you

Email message
```

If you change the TO: to not have < and >, it will assume the whole string is an email address and if its not just the email address, it will fail.

So if it is `You you@example.com` it will fail because `you you@example.com` does not exist. There is a you user, but not a `you you` user. If you just write `you`, it will fail because it cannot understand the domain you.